# Modify wordpress query parameter inside loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change a WP_query parameter if there is not any posts matching the query.
Specifically I want to change the monthnum value, if there is not any posts to show of the current month, I want to run the query again with the new monthnum value.

```
$query = new WP_Query (array('category_name'=> $cat,'year' => $ano, 'monthnum' => $monthnum, 'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, 'post__not_in' => array($id)));   

if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 

    //do something      

    endwhile;
else:

    $monthnum = $monthnum - 1;
    if($monthnum == 0){
        $monthnum = 12;
    }

    /*
      here I want to run the query again with the new $monthnum value
    */

endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

Do you know the solution? Help me, please! Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly this isn't just an alternate query if no posts are found, you want to keep reducing the month val by 1 until posts are found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can change the parameters to an old`WP_Query`-- I wouldn't know. But it's easy enough to create a new `WP_Query` for each query: Just save your parameter array in a variable, instead of passing it directly to `WP_Query`, and you can modify it as often as you want. Abbreviated code:

```
$params = array('category_name'=> $cat, 'year'=> $ano, 'monthnum'=> $monthnum, 
                'posts_per_page'=> $posts_per_page, 'post__not_in'=> array($id));

$query = new WP_Query($params);   
while (! $query->have_posts()) {
    $params['monthnum'] -= 1;
    if ($params['monthnum'] == 0) {
        $params['year'] -= 1;
        $params['monthnum'] = 12;
    }

    $query = new WP_Query($params);
}
```